# Only pipe on Success

Tags: command-line, pipe

Is there a way in the Linux command line, to only have a command pipe its output to another, when the command didn't fail?

```
$ cmda | cmdb
```

I would like it, so when `cmda` returns a status code other than 0, its output doesn't get redirected to `cmdb`.

Answer (score 8):

You will need to store the output in a variable to accomplish this. Here is an example:

```
if output=$(cmda); then
  printf '%s' "$output" | cmdb
fi
```

Comment: Does not seem to work for `command info put`

Comment: @winklerrr can you post an example? This works fine for me `if output=$(command info ls) ; then echo "successful because 'ls' exists" ; else echo failure; fi`